# how to judge move_base has go to the goal?

Tags: navigation, move-base

[image: Rosanswers logo]

We can control the robot to a goal, using base_move and amcl.

but i can not judge that when the robot reached the goal.

I think, we can judge the vel or the tf not change to do it .

but, I think that ,it must have better solution.

I use rqt_graph and rosrun tf view_frames list all.
but , I can not find any solution than I do.

anyone can help me to solve it,

thanks!

EDIT1:

when the route is short the status always be 3 , when the robot nav to a long distance the status change to 1 and then change to 3.

I want to know why , the status is not change the status 3 SUCCEEDED->1ACTIVE->3 SUCCEEDED ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/237748/how-to-judge-move_base-has-go-to-the-goal?/) by [ligang](https://answers.ros.org/users/26953/ligang/) on ROS Answers with karma: 31 on 2016-06-22

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

you can check the topic `move_base/status` ([more info](http://wiki.ros.org/move_base#Action_API)).

answering EDIT 1:

you probably see the status as 3 (SUCCEEDED) for short paths because move_base "thinks" it already arrived at the goal position, probably because the goal is inside the tolerance.

for longer paths, it should first be 1 (ACTIVE) and then 3 (SUCCEEDED).

---

Originally posted by [Procópio](https://answers.ros.org/users/1112/proc%C3%B3pio/) with karma: 4402 on 2016-06-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) on 2016-06-23**:
Note though, that this only works if you use the action interface. If you use the `move_base_simple/goal` topic interface (which you do if you set the goal in `rviz`) this will not work.

But in the end, the only way to do it is to use the action interface, so @Procopio is right.

**Comment by [ligang](https://answers.ros.org/users/26953/ligang/) on 2016-06-23**:
use the action interface,
can you provide a simple example, I am a fresh in ROS.

**Comment by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) on 2016-06-23**:
best work through the [actionlib tutorials](http://wiki.ros.org/actionlib/Tutorials)